# why Radio Button in Alert Dialog doesn't update?

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button, android-alertdialog

So I try to use Radio button to choose some option inside Alert dialog. It looks like this:

[image].

The radio button remains inactive when I click on it. But when I close the alert dialog and open it again, the radio button is activated. For example, I chose the second option, but the radio button still shows the first option is active. But if I select the second option, then tap elsewhere to close the alert dialog, when I open it again I find that the second option is enabled

My code look like this:

```dart
AlertDialog(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    side: BorderSide(
      color: blackColor,
      width: 3,
    ),
  ),
  content: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          on_progress,
          Radio(
            value: 1,
            groupValue: _StatusVal,
            onChanged: (int? value) {
              setState(() {
                _StatusVal = value!;
                print(_StatusVal);
                (_StatusVal == 1)
                    ? progress = true
                    : progress = false;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          selesai,
          Radio(
            value: 2,
            groupValue: _StatusVal,
            onChanged: (int? value) {
              setState(() {
                _StatusVal = value!;
                print(_StatusVal);
                (_StatusVal == 1)
                    ? progress = true
                    : progress = false;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I have two item inside my alert dialog. It seems that the radio button doesn't updated because I put it inside my alert dialog. How to activate the button inside the alert dialog?

Answer (score 3):

Try to add your `AlertDialog` inside [**`StatefulBuilder`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) hope its help to you.

```
StatefulBuilder(
   builder: (context, StateSetter setState) {
   return AlertDialog();
  }
);
```